# document.getElementById returns always null

Tags: javascript

Ive got this piece of code:

```html
<form class="register" id="reg-form">
        <input type="text" class="input-box" placeholder="Username" id="username" required><br><br>
        <input type="text" class="input-box" placeholder="Full Name" id="name" required><br><br>
        <input type="email" class="input-box" placeholder="Email" id="email" required><br><br>
        <input type="password" class="input-box" placeholder="Password" id="password" required><br><br>
        <input type="password" class="input-box" placeholder="Repeat Password" id="passwordrep" required><br><br><br>
        <button class="btn-rounded-md black" id="reg-btn">Register</button>
    </form>
```

and this js:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  var reppassword = document.getElementById('passwordrep').value;

  document.getElementById('reg-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password == reppassword) {
      console.log("Passwords match. Submitting...");

      auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(userCredential => {
        console.log('Signed up!');
      });
    }
  });
}
```

but all vars created at the start of the js return all null. Any ideas?

Comment: `null` or empty strings? When your code runs, all those `<input>` values will be empty

Comment: You're trying to get values from these elements on load, in which they will be empty. You should move them inside the "submit" function, at which point, you can assume these inputs have been filled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're retrieving the values on pageload, not on submit; they'll always be empty (not null, but the empty string). Change to:

```
document.getElementById('reg-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  var reppassword = document.getElementById('passwordrep').value;

  if (password == reppassword) {
    console.log("Passwords match. Submitting...");

    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(userCredential => {
      console.log('Signed up!');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment:  stupid error. I never thought it could be that